# How to enable/disable use of NumericUpDown boxes if the maximum sum has been reacheed

Tags: vb.net, forms, sum, numericupdown

I'm making a game in VB in which the user defines the stats for their character. On the character creation screen, the user has 5 skills, all set at 1, and has a maximum of 10 skillpoints which they may spend. Once all points have been used, the user can't exceed this number.

Skillpoints are applied to their respective skills using NumericUpDown boxes which would associate the number selected and store it in a variable. How do I get the program to recognise that the skillpoint limit has been reached and additional points can't be distributed? Think of RPG character creations

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles numUD1.ValueChanged
    If maxcheck() Then
        numUD1.Value -= 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Do that for all of your `NumericUpDown` fields. They each call the Function `maxcheck()` below:

```
Private Function maxcheck()
    If numUD1.Value + numUD2.Value + numUD3.Value + numUD4.Value + numUD5.Value > 15 Then '10 skill points + 5 starting points
        MessageBox.Show("All skill points spent!")
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

You might be able to do it in one handler, but I wasn't able to figure out how to get which field had been changed when I did that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim totalSkillPoints As Int16 = 15

    Private Sub nudStrength_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nudStrength.ValueChanged
        If nudStrength.Value + nudInt.Value > totalSkillPoints Then
            nudStrength.Value -= 1
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub numInt_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nudInt.ValueChanged
        If nudStrength.Value + nudInt.Value > totalSkillPoints Then
            nudInt.Value -= 1
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can just check all the values together against the value of your maximum potential skill points. When your at the number just revert the change by subtracting.

Edit: charlie's way of making a function will look much cleaner and make it easier to add more skills in the future.